# Compactar todos os arquivos JS do NodeJs (node_modules) diminui a performance?

Tags: node.js, gulp

Na minha aplicação estou usando o Gulp para compactar todos os meus arquivos **JS** que ficam dentro da pasta **node_modules**, minha dúvida é em questão de performance, é uma prática ruim fazer isso ou não?

Caso tenham alguma sugestão vai ajudar muito!

Comment: A leitura de um arquivo js compactado é sempre mais rápida. Agora, você vai servir *todos* os arquivos dos seus módulos do node junto com a sua aplicação? O interessante é minificar os arquivos de produção. Não sei se compactar os de desenvolvimento trariam algum benefício, a não ser para a execução das suas *tasks*...

Comment: Um pergunta, porque você está compactando os arquivos do node_modules? Questão de deploy? Os módulos que você instala via NPM (que ficam dentro da pasta node_modules) não deveriam ser mexidos.

Comment: Não estou mexendo, é questão de estrutura. A pasta dos módulos fica fora da pasta que vai para produção (public) e preciso trazer todos as dependências Javascript para dentro dela, uma alternativa que pensei é copiar tudo usando o gulp.

Answer (score 1):

Existem diversas maneiras de se trabalhar com as dependências dos módulos instalados via NPM.

Compactar toda pasta node_modules e fazer deploy dela, nunca é uma boa opção. Álias fazer referência no seu projeto direto a node_modules não é uma boa prática por várias razões, algumas delas são:

1. Alguma library pode ser atualizada via NPM e quebrar sua aplicação
2. Você vai estar compactando muitos arquivos atoa, depois dentro do node_modules não tem apenas a library que você usa, sem a versão prod (não minificada) tem a versão developer (minificada) tem scripts de teste, geralmetne README files etc etc.

Uma boa prática é.

Você ter a seguinte estrutura (por exemplo)

```
node_modules/
----- angularjs/
---------- angular.js
---------- angular.min.js
---------- vários outros arquivos
```

Sua app aqui

```
app/
----- js/
---------- libs/
--------------- develop/
-------------------- angular.js (aqui é o módulo do angular instalado via NPM sem ser minificadom usado geralmente para debug ou olhar o código para entender o que a library faz)
dist /
(dentro da pasta dist que seus arquivos vão estar todos minificados, otimizados e compactados)
```

Você pode fazer essa cópia via GULP, GRUNT ou até mesmo manualmente se preferir.

Assim também usar o GULP ou GRUNT para fazer a minificação dos arquivos js, (meuarquivojs.min.js) para fazer o deploy para o servidor.

O bom dessa prática é caso você queria atualizar algum módulo, você pode comparar via qualquer merge tool (WinMerge por exemplo) e ver o que foi realmente atualizado ou alterado com relação ao o que você está utilizando.

Assim pode atualizar os módulos sem medo, pois não impactam diretamente na sua aplicação a não ser que você escolhar atualizar eles conscientemente.

De qualquer forma, nunca faça delpoy da pasta node_modules.